# Infinite recursion with \tl_map_variable:nNn

Tags: expl3, latex3, recursion

I'm trying to use one of LaTeX3's mapping commands `\tl_map_variable:nNn` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_foo_tl {x}

\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl
\tl_map_variable:nNn {abc} \l_foo_tl {\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl}
\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The expected output is `xabcx`. However, the map function seems to get stuck into an infinite loop, and I'm not sure why that happens. Even changing the token list `{abc}` into `{}` yields the same outcome.

From enabling tracing of macros in the log file, I can tell that the problem is related to `\q_recursion_tail` which is expanded to itself over and over again.

Could anyone explain what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit (by BLF):** This has now been fixed: `\tl_map_variable:nNn` and related functions leave the variable equal to the last item in the token list, rather than to a trailing marker.

`\tl_map_variable:nNn` does not create a group level, so at the end of the code `\l_foo_tl` contains the last token in the list, which is `\q_recursion_tail` (which is inserted after your `abc` to detect the end of the list). Then, when you do `\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl` you expand `\q_recursion_tail`, leading to infinite recursion.

`\tl_map_variable:nNn` expands once to:

```latex
\__tl_map_variable:Nnn #2 {#3} #1 \q_recursion_tail
\prg_break_point:Nn \tl_map_break: { }
```

and the first thing `\__tl_map_variable:Nnn` does is to assign the first item in `#1` (which eventually ends up being `\q_recursion_tail`) to `#2`, which is your `⟨tl var⟩`. You should use another `⟨tl var⟩` to avoid that:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bar_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_foo_tl {x}

\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl
\tl_map_variable:nNn {abc} \l_bar_tl { \tl_use:N \l_bar_tl }
\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The documentation doesn't mention (not that I could find, at least), the contents and usability of the `⟨tl var⟩` after the end of `\tl_map_variable:nNn`, so I don't know if this is by design or not.

However you can define a version of `\tl_map_variable:nNn` which saves the value of `⟨tl var⟩` and restores it when the function ends:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \siracusa_tl_map_variable:nNn #1#2
  {
    \exp_args:NV
    \__siracusa_tl_map_variable:nnNn #2 {#1} #2
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siracusa_tl_map_variable:nnNn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \tl_map_variable:nNn {#2} #3 {#4}
    \tl_set:Nx #3 { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_foo_tl {x}

\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl
\siracusa_tl_map_variable:nNn {abc} \l_foo_tl { \tl_use:N \l_foo_tl }
\tl_use:N \l_foo_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I think it would be better if `\tl_map_variable:nNn` should manually save and restore the value of `#2`.

Comment: To me this behavior also seems a bit unexpected. The documentation says "The assignments to the `<variable>` are local." which made me think all changes inside the mapping functions do already occur inside a local group, or are at least reverted afterwards.

Comment: @siracusa That sentence means that the variable used should be `\l_whatever_tl` (instead of `\g_...`) and that whatever assignment is done, it will be restored if the function is used in a group. But indeed, the behaviour is unexpected (and undocumented). There is an ongoing [discussion](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/581) in the l3 repository about this.

Comment: Please don't use internal functions (starting with `__`).  They may change with no warning whatsoever.  Here it's really not needed: `\tl_new:N \l__siracusa_save_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \siracusa_tl_map_variable:nNn #1#2#3 { \tl_set_eq:NN \l__siracusa_save_tl #2 \tl_map_variable:nNn {#1} #2 {#3} \tl_set_eq:NN #2 \l__siracusa_save_tl }` or many other variants of that would work fine.